# Why when I start the SSM agent on my EC2 instance I get "Unit is masked."?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssm

I noticed that my new machine isn't registering with AWS SSM.  I sshed to the EC2 machine and ran the following and got very cryptic errors:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-15-143 ~]$ sudo systemctl enable amazon-ssm-agent
Failed to execute operation: Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-15-143 ~]$ sudo systemctl start amazon-ssm-agent
Failed to start amazon-ssm-agent.service: Unit is masked.
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-15-143 ~]$
```

I tried googling and found nothing useful.  Maybe SSM isn't setup correctly?  Help!

Comment: @jww Oops!  Sorry.  Can I move it?  And where to?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured this out.  It seems the latest version of AWS Linux already has SSM running on it, and my setup script was re-installing SSM a second time which was overriding the original installation.

Specifically, I had to remove this line:

```
sudo yum -y install https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm"
```

Don't run it!